# SQLite3 command line: how do you cancel a command?

Tags: command-line, line-editor, sqlite

I made a mistake writing a command at the SQLite command prompt, which I now want to abort, this is how my command line looks

```
sqlite> select * from todos'
   ...> '
   ...> ;^C
```

In this case, likely because I have opened a quote, I can't even hit `ENTER` to run the command. I just get a line continuation, that would still be less than ideal because I would be having to run bad code and cause and error, just to regain control of the prompt.
How can I cancel the line/command and get returned back to a prompt?

Comment: Maybe ^D will close stdin for `sqlite` and make it exit...

Comment: @Ralph ctrl D makes sqlite exit the entire session, including losing any in memory databases - if you hapoen to be running any.

Answer (score 25):

The `sqlite3` interface uses the ReadLine library for command line editing. You can erase a full line with <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> but once you have pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the line has been accepted and is no longer editable.

As you've [noticed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291083/sqlite3-command-line-how-do-you-cancel-a-command#comment509438_291083), sending <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> will prompt the client to exit, which is not what you want.

Your best bet is to

1. close any string, and then,
2. before issuing a final `;`, generate a deliberate syntax error.

In your example:

```
sqlite> select * from todos'
   ...> '
   ...> *** I made a mistake
   ...> ;
Error: near "*": syntax error
sqlite>
```

This will ensure that nothing gets executed, and it will leave you in the SQLite session with any temporary tables intact.

Comment: thanks, yes I thought that might be best workaround

Comment: If you have pressed enter after an arrow key, i.e., you have something like `> ^[[A` and then `...>`, then you have to close the brackets to cancel that: `> ]];`. It really should support Ctrl+C for this. It's obnoxious this way.